# Webserver and application servers on different servers for MS teams Bot application

Tags: python-3.x, botframework, bots

I have MS teams bot application, my security team requesting to configure the proxy web application to  forward the request to Bot application
(Like data flow  MS team Client-->Azure Bot Service-->Webserver-->Application Server) Note there is firewall between Azure Bot Service and Webserver.

Here my questions, how to configure proxy webserver to forward the request to Python Bot Application hosted on application server. Can we use IIS or Apache ? How to configure the webservers to forward the request and send the response to Client?

Thanks
SSN

Comment: There's a lot of information we need before we can help you. What do you mean when you say webserver? What is the difference in your mind between a webserver and an application server? It looks like you're saying the application server is where you're running your bot, so why not just say bot instead of application server? Is your webserver running some kind of app that you can write code for like a bot? Is it ASP.NET or what? And what does SSN stand for?

Comment: Are you still working on this?